# Interspire Email Marketer Configuration

Tags: php, mysql, marketing, bulk-email

I'm trying to set up Interspire's [Email Marketer](http://www.interspire.com/emailmarketer/) for a client. I have a working configuration of it on the VPS but this one is having issues! I have transferred it from their old server and setup the new database...

I'm thinking it could be something to do with the PHP settings / MySQL memory or buffer.

When I send to a small list, it works fine, but when its faced with a larger list it won't do the business... it won't even start sending.

I've been comparing the two configurations:

- http://oldhabs.com/emailmarketer/check_iem.php (This one works)
- http://servedby.intelligentmedia.co.uk/check_iem.php (This is the one that won't send to a large list)

I've been getting these errors from Interspire itself:

> Error       Resource is not really a resource    Internal    May 15
>   2012 07:20:05
>       Location::
>
> /var/www/vhosts/intelligentmedia.co.uk/servedby/admin/functions/api/jobs.php
>   (Line 1068)
>          Error       Table 'imsemailsender.email_user_permissions' doesn't exist    Internal    May 15 2012 07:20:05
>       Query:
>
> SELECT l.listid, l.ownername, l.owneremail FROM email_lists l,
>   email_user_permissions p WHERE l.listid IN(198) AND l.ownerid =
>   p.userid AND p.area = 'lists' AND p.subarea = 'bouncesettings'
>
> Location::
>
> /var/www/vhosts/intelligentmedia.co.uk/servedby/admin/functions/api/jobs.php
>   (Line 1065)
>          Notice       Undefined index: ownerid    Internal    May 15 2012 07:15:54    Undefined index: ownerid in
>   /var/www/vhosts/intelligentmedia.co.uk/servedby/admin/functions/send.php
>   at 213 File   Line   Function
>   /var/www/vhosts/intelligentmedia.co.uk/servedby/admin/functions/send.php
>   213   HandlePHPErrors
>   /var/www/vhosts/intelligentmedia.co.uk/servedby/admin/com/init.php
>   548   Send->Process
>   /var/www/vhosts/intelligentmedia.co.uk/servedby/admin/index.php   76
>   require_once
>
> ```
>    Notice       Undefined index: jobdetails    Internal    May 15 2012 07:15:54    Undefined index: jobdetails in
> ```
>
> /var/www/vhosts/intelligentmedia.co.uk/servedby/admin/functions/send.php
>   at 212 File   Line   Function
>   /var/www/vhosts/intelligentmedia.co.uk/servedby/admin/functions/send.php
>   212   HandlePHPErrors
>   /var/www/vhosts/intelligentmedia.co.uk/servedby/admin/com/init.php
>   548   Send->Process
>   /var/www/vhosts/intelligentmedia.co.uk/servedby/admin/index.php

I know the top error is to do with the wrong bounced address... I think. Would this stop the send to that list?

I've checked the server logs, and I'm not getting any errors.